# Apache/htaccess disallow other domains with same IP

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I just setup a brand new server at my host (NOT on a shared host btw), and apparently this IP was used previously and I keep getting requests in the apache logs for people going to that old domain (that has the same IP that has not been changed in DNS). Is there a simple way to tell Apache or htaccess to ONLY allow the domains I have defined there to serve my site, and ignore/drop/redirect others that aren't to my domain?

Comment: Do you have full access to the Apache installation and is this linux or windows?

Comment: I have full access (including webmin) and this is Ubuntu 16

Comment: have a look at this [answer](http://serverfault.com/a/444218/280715). define your first virtual host as a catch all and all other sites as new virtual hosts.

Comment: Here you go, it was answered over on Information Security: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83362/how-can-i-stop-someone-from-displaying-my-website-on-his-domain?noredirect=1&lq=1